# Move word-by-word in Powershell Intellisense

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've achieved Intellisense from the `Powershell` via PSReadLine, but unlike `fish` shell where a word from the path can be concluded by hitting `Ctrl + Right Arrow`, I can't find any such shortcut or solution for this issue in Powershell. If any solutions, I please welcome them.

**Example :**

[image]

I now want to obtain `cd '.\PICS\KIRAN\'` only.

In `fish` shell, it's the scenario where you click `Ctrl + Right Arrow` for 2 times and then you get the expected result.

What should I do to obtain the same result in Windows `Powershell` ?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/announcing-psreadline-2-1-with-predictive-intellisense/#:~:text=AcceptNextSuggestionWord%20is%20built%20within%20the%20function%20ForwardWord%2C)

Comment: Yeah, thanks!! This worked for me after binding with Ctrl+RightArrow !!

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (forward)
- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> (backword)